# $B=A(I+F)$ with $\|F\|<1$ implies $\|A^{-1}B\|<1/(1-\|B^{-1}A-I\|)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be invertible $n\times n$ matrix and $B=A(I+F)$ with $\|F\|<1$ where norm is consistent and submultiplicative. I learned that $I+F$ is invertible and $\|(I+F)^{-1}\|<1/(1-\|F\|)$. So we get $\|B^{-1}A\|<1/(1-\|F\|)$.

But is it true that $\|A^{-1}B\|<1/(1-\|B^{-1}A-I\|)$? The explanation is follows, which I couldn't understand: If $\|F\|=\|A^{-1}B-I\|\ll1$, then $B^{-1}$ is an approximate inverse of $A$. Interchanging $A$ and $B$ gives the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** This isn't even true in the scalar case. Let $A=B=1$ and $F=0$. Consider the *double* of the operator $2$-norm (i.e. $\|X\|=2|X|$). Then
$$\|A^{-1}B\|=2>\frac1{1-\|B^{-1}A-I\|}=1.$$

However, the statement is true if strict inequalty is replaced by "$\le$", the matrix norm is an *induced* norm (instead of merely a consistent norm) and $\|F\|\ll1$ (rather than $\|F\|<1$). As $\|\cdot\|$ is an induced norm, $\|I\|=1$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
\|I+F\| &\le \|I\| + \|F\|\\
&= 1+\|F\|\\
&\le 1 + \|I+F\| \|(I+F)^{-1}F\|.
\end{align*}
When $\|F\|\ll1$, we have $\|(I+F)^{-1}F\|<1$. So, the above inequaltiy can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\|A^{-1}B\| = \|I+F\| \le \frac1{ 1 - \|(I+F)^{-1}F\|} = \frac1{ 1 - \|I-B^{-1}A\|}.
\end{align*}